# The difference between redis and datacache?

Tags: caching, redis, ibm-cloud

Bluemix offers [DataCache](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/data-cache/) and [Redis](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/redis-by-compose/), which both offer key/value store.

What are the differences and what are the typical use cases for both? I am trying to decide which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

Interviewed some users of both:

DataCache is an in-memory data**grid**, while Redis is an in-memory data**base**. The grid doesn't have a persistence function, you have to code it yourself. This is more work, but also more flexible. DataCache expiry is set to a whole collection, while Redis expires key by key.

Redis is [BSD licensed](http://redis.io/topics/license) OpenSource, while DataCache is build on IBM's propriety Websphere Extreme Scale architecture. It's in they eye of the beholder what you prefer.